# Unable to add files in git dowloaded via composer ( PHP)

Tags: php, git

I am working on a php project and relying on composer for installing dependencies which is working fine in my case but when I try to commit the files things get tricky.

A simplified view of my composer.json is as follows.

```html
"require": {
        "apache/log4php": "2.3.0",
        "asojon/mysql-pdo-wrapper": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "psr-0":{
            "": ""
        }
    }
```

When I ran composer install it created 3 folders namely composer,apache and asojon and autoload.php file under vendor folder.Then I went ahead and comited the vendor folder and now when I clone my project repo all the files under vendor/apache and vendor/asojon are empty. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: What does your .gitignore file look like?

Comment: probably your .gitignore file stops those files from being tracked by Git

Comment: As another alternate theory, are you cloning the correct repository? That is, are you cloning the repository that has the vendor commits?

Comment: I searched for .gitignore file in my project and found one as follows 
./vendor/asojon/mysql-pdo-wrapper/.gitignore
 I deleted that .gitignore file still its not working

Comment: @ChrisForrence Kindly elaborate a bit .I could't get you.

Comment: .gitignore file in ./vendor/asojon/mysql-pdo-wrapper/ had the following contents.

**/vendor/**

Comment: @STandon Sure; you had committed the vendor folder to your local repository, right? When you cloned your repository, did you clone that local repository, or did you clone a remote repository (like, on GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.)?

Comment: Also, the right .gitignore folder would be in the root of your project. If it's not there, then that doesn't appear to be the problem. Might want to run `git checkout -- vendor/asojon/mysql-pdo-wrapper/.gitignore` to restore that .gitignore file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69122/discussion-between-standon-and-chrisforrence).

Answer (score 0):

You should not commit you vendor folder but only your composer json, it is why composer exist.
Every time you `git clone` your repo, you should run `composer install`.